# What would be the format of urls.py for class based views?

Tags: django

I am new to django so i want to know how to write urls.py for a project.
I  want to make backend api for inventory management system.
When i type localhost:8000/inventory_backend/dep/, I am having following error:
**Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
The current path, inventory_backend/dep/, didn't match any of these.

My code for mysite/urls.py**

```
   from django.conf.urls import include, url
  from django.contrib import admin



   urlpatterns =  [
              url(r'^inventory_backend/', include('inventory_backend.urls') 
   ),
               url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls) ,
             ]
```

**inventory_backend/urls.py:**

```
 from inventory_backend.views import DepartmentsView,InventoriesView

 from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()

router.register(r'dep/',DepartmentsView )

router.register(r'inv/',InventoriesView )

 urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from inventory_backend.models import Departments,Inventories


class DepartmentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model : Departments
    fields: ('id','name')


 class InventoriesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
dept = DepartmentsSerializer(many=True)
class Meta:
    model : Inventories
    fields : ('id','name','description','dept')
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Departments(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Inventories(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
dept = models.ManyToManyField(Departments)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from inventory_backend.models import Inventories,Departments
from inventory_backend.serializers import InventoriesSerializer, 
DepartmentsSerializer


class DepartmentsView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Departments.objects.all();
serializer_class = DepartmentsSerializer;



class InventoriesView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Inventories.objects.all();
serializer_class  = InventoriesSerializer;
```

Comment: Add your inventory_backend app urls file code

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your inventory_backend.urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
        ]
```